# How can I move a dojo script in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, dialog, dojo, dijit.form

I have a working JavaScript page that uses dojo to check the results of a `dijit/Dialog` form.

```
<div class="content">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Form Dialog" style="display: none">
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-id="myForm">
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="submit" data-dojo-args="e">
        require(["dijit/registry"],function(registry){
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
            if(!myForm.isValid()){ alert("Please fix fields"); return; }
            var inputField = registry.byId("input-field");
            var resultVal = inputField.get("value");
            console.log("Would submit "+resultVal+" here via dojo/xhr.");
            window.alert("Would submit "+resultVal+" here via dojo/xhr.");
            myFormDialog.hide();
        });
    </script>
    <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        <label for='foo'>Foo: </label>
        <input type="text" name="input-field" id="input-field" value="Foo here" required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit">OK</button>
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button"
                data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){myFormDialog.hide();}">Cancel</button>
    </div>
 </form>
</div>
<p>When pressing this button the dialog will popup:</p>
<button id="buttonThree" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Show me!
<script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
    myFormDialog.show();
</script>
</button>

</div>
<script>
  require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dojo/on"]);';
</script>
```

I want to move the script in the form to the bottom of the page, so that I can integrate it with another page.

(This code is generated by PHP, and I use a heredoc to include code from a dojotools example.)

I tried the following code:

```
<div class="content">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Form Dialog" style="display: none">
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-id="myForm">
    <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        <label for='foo'>Foo: </label>
        <input type="text" name="input-field" id="input-field" data-dojo-id="input-field" value="Foo here" required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" data-dojo-id="my-button" id="my-button" data-dojo-args="e">OK</button>
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button"
                data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){myFormDialog.hide();}">Cancel</button>
    </div>
 </form>
</div>

<p>When pressing this button the dialog will popup:</p>
<button id="buttonThree" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Show me!
  <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
      myFormDialog.show();
  </script>
</button>
</div>
<script>
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/registry", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/TextBox", ],
function(dom, on, registry){
  on(dom.byId("my-button"), "click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
      console.log("Reached on() function.");
  })
});
</script>
```

This results in the following on the page (copied from Chrome developer tools, where console does not show any syntax errors):

```
<div class="content">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Form Dialog" style="display: none">
    <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-id="myForm">
      <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        <label for='foo'>Foo: </label>
        <input type="text" name="input-field" id="input-field" data-dojo-id="input-field" value="Foo here" required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
      </div>
      <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" data-dojo-id="my-button" id="my-button" data-dojo-args="e">OK</button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button"
          data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){myFormDialog.hide();}">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <p>When pressing this button the dialog will popup:</p>
  <button id="buttonThree" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Show me!
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
      myFormDialog.show();
    </script>
  </button>
</div>
<script>
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/registry", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/TextBox", ],
function(dom, on, registry){
  on(dom.byId("my-button"), "click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
      console.log("Reached on() function.");
  })
});</script>
```

In this case, the `on()` handler does not appear to be called. The **Show Me** button appears.

If you click it, it shows the form with the Foo field. If you put a value in the field and click the **OK** button, the form disappears. But no message is posted to the console.

Does anyone have a suggestion why the script will work as part of the form, but not as a separate call on the page?

The original code comes from the "Forms and Functionality in Dialogs" section of the dijit/Dialog page (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html#dijit-dialog).

Answer (score 0):

First the  `on(dom.byId("my-button"), "click", function(e){...})`  will not fire because it's attached to a dom not wich is replaced after by dojo parser ,

also you have declared the button with both `data-dojo-id` and `id` ,

note that `data-dojo-id` (don't use the minus  `-` in naming here use underscore `_` instead ) create a global element with this id in window object , so later you can access your element directly like here `my_button.on(...)`

while by the `id` it create a widget with `widgetid=id` in order to access it by `dijit/registry` .

Second : the important point  is in order to access those widget here you should wait until they are all parsed , so using callback function dojo/ready to be sur that all widgets are correctly parsed ,

Soo in your case after the ready (widget parsed , there is no generated dom item with `id="my-button"`  its replaced by the widget itselef ) 
thus the submit button will submit directly and no preventdefault actionned there also no message

See below working snippet :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {
    isDebug: true,
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Form Dialog" style="display: none">
    <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-id="myForm" action="#">
      <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        <label for='foo'>Foo: </label>
        <input type="text" name="input-field" id="input-field" data-dojo-id="input-field" value="Foo here" required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"/>
      </div>
      <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" data-dojo-id="my_button" id="my-button" data-dojo-args="e">OK</button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){myFormDialog.hide();}">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <p>When pressing this button the dialog will popup:</p>
  <button id="buttonThree" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Show me!
  <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
      myFormDialog.show();
  </script>
</button>
  <script>
    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"],
      function(dom, on, registry, ready) {

        ready(function() {
          // my_button same as = registry.byId("my-button");
          my_button.on("click", function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
            console.log("Reached on() function.",myForm.validate());
            if(myForm.validate()) {
              //do som stuff here and then close dilaog
            }
          });
          
        });

      });
  </script>


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, Boo. I will give this a try when I next get a chance and post the results. I think this will be very helpful.